# SSLHandshakeException Below Android 6.0 (marshmallow)

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

Error Log.

[SSLHandshakeException Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzWFM.png)

**only in marshmallow it's working fine else not working.**

i am getting SSLHandshakeException in all android version only work fine in marshmallow.

```
public DefaultHttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                .getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params,
                HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_SO_TIMEOUT);
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                params, registry);

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        return httpclient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        SSLContext sslContext = getSslContext();

```
    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
            KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);
        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
            boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host,
                port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post error log text here instead of screenshot.

Comment: If you get a HandshakeError for a specific URL add this URL to the question. If this is a general problem with your code for all URLs add this information to your question too. If you did not try other URLs like google.com, paypal.com etc.

Comment: do you figured it ?